# Delphi issues with GUI in a Callback

Tags: c++, delphi, callback

I've a C++ video processing DLL working very well but its callback is freezing my APP GUI ; here's my Delphi code :

```
procedure FramesDone_cb(pvfDone: Integer;var cancel:Boolean);cdecl;
begin
    // this callback is freezing the whole GUI
    Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := pvfDone;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
vp: VideoProcessor;
 begin
  vp := VideoProcessor_Create();
  VideoProcessor_SetFramesDone_cb(vp,FramesDone_cb);
end;
```

I tried to put an anonymous thread in the callback but i always get **Thread creation error** , please is there any fix/proper way so that this CB doesn't freeze my App GUI .

Comment: Can you show us how the callback is declared in your c++ library?

Comment: Impossible for us to tell you what the threading rules and model of your library are. Only somebody with knowledge of the library can do that.

Comment: many thanks , the callback does work even in my delphi App ,the only issue is when the progresbar updates its position here the main GUI get frozen .

Comment: Try to post a message to the GUI instead.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := pvfDone;` and check if it's happening in the main thread or not.

Comment: I would suggest using an atomic variable to hold the progress and update the progress UI control in a timer event. No need to update the display more often than the refresh rate of the display. Also make sure progress has been made before updating the control to avoid unneeded repaints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest updating an atomic variable in your callback then update the progress bar in a timer event that triggers not more often than once per display refresh.

```
procedure FramesDone_cb(pvfDone: Integer;var cancel:Boolean);cdecl;
begin
   // CurrentProgress is an integer so can be updated atomically
   CurrentProgress := pvfDone;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ProgressBar1.Position != CurrentProgress then
     ProgressBar1.Position := CurrentProgress;
end;
```

This decouples the callback from the UI and avoids excessive updates of the progress bar.